# Hashicorp Vault migration from storage type `file` to `raft`

Tags: kubernetes, data-migration, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to migrate our Hashicorp Vault standalone with storage type `file` running in our RKE2 cluster to a Hashicorp Vault HA with storage type `raft`. But still getting some issues. [We're using the Helm chart version 0.22.0](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/hashicorp/vault). So these are the steps I followed:

1. Create a temporary Vault Raft running in RKE2 with 1 replica (don't initialize vault)
2. `Exec` into the old Vault container with the storage type `file`
3. Go to the `/vault/` folder and create a `raft` folder in it
4. Run the command `vault operator migrate --config migrate.hcl`
   The migrate.hcl file looks like this:

```
storage_source "file" {
  path = "/vault/data/"
}

storage_destination "raft" {
  path = "/vault/raft/"
  node_id = "vault-raft-0"
}

cluster_addr="https://127.0.0.1:8201"
```

5. The migration is complete and it created a `vault.db` file into `/vault/raft/` and a `raft.db` file into `/vault/raft/raft/` including an empty folder called `snapshots`.
6. Then I copied this whole `/vault/raft/` folder to my local pc and copied it again to the temporary Vault Raft container. It has the same data storage mount path, so: `/vault/raft/`
7. After copying the files I re-deployed the temporary Vault Raft since the pvc won't be deleted and checked if it has still the copied `.db` files in it.
8. In the end I tried to unseal it, but after running the third command Iit returns the following message: `Error unsealing: context deadline exceeded`

Am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: Steps 1 and 7 both seem unclear. Why did you need to create a temporary new cluster if it was not used? When you re-deployed the new cluster, did you re-initialize it with the migrated data? This should probably be tried instead with a normal immutable infra upgrade process transposed onto the equivalent k8s deployment methodology.

Comment: Because that are the steps they are recommending in the documentation of Hashicorp Vault and posts' on the forum of Hashicorp

Comment: How is it possible to re-initialize it with the migrated data if there's no data in an existing persistent volume? You first have to create this PV and PVC's and copy this data into it, right?

Comment: Re-initializing with the migrated data is the likely root cause here. Compare this to restoring a backup in Vault on a new cluster: you would not do that prior to initiliziation either. I would still imagine this would be easier with the upgrade process than a full on re-creation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a little bit late, but working flow for me sounds like this:

1. create migrate.hcl with content :

```
storage_source "file" {
 path = "/vault/data/"
}
 storage_destination "raft" {
 path = "/vault/data/"
}
cluster_addr = "https://vault-0.vault-internal:8201"
```

2. Then run `vault operator migrate -config=migrate.hcl`
3. Uninstall your previous deployment.
4. Install deployment with raft enabled.
5. At the vault-0 run `vault operator unseal`
6. At the other pods run `vault operator raft join http://vault-0.vault-internal:8200` and `vault operator unseal`.

This worked for me